# MVC en visual basic

Tags: vb.net

tengo este condigo el cual me permite acceder alos valores desde un texbox

```
@Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.apellidos, New With {.class = "control-lebel"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.apellidos, New With {.class = "form-control"})
```

quiero realizar esto con un RadioButton "para escoger un genero ya sea masculino o femenino" como puedo usarlo con el @Html.RadioButtonFor

Answer (score 0):

Habría que ver tu cómo tienes definido tu modelo pero a ver si con este ejemplo te sirve.

Si, por ejemplo, tienes definida una enumeración `Genero`:

```
Public Enum Genero
    Femenino
    Masculino
End Enum
```

Y, en tu modelo, una propiedad `GeneroPersona` del tipo `Genero`:

```
Property GeneroPersona() As Genero
```

El código en tu vista podría ser algo así:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.GeneroPersona, New With {.class = "control-label"})
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.GeneroPersona, Genero.Masculino, New With {.Id = "rdMasculino" })
    <label for="rdMasculino">Masculino</label>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(Function(m) m.GeneroPersona, Genero.Femenino, New With {.Id = "rdFemenino"})
    <label for="rdFemenino">Femenino</label>
```

El método `RadioButtonFor` te crea los radiobuttons y le asigno un `Id` específico para poder asociarle una etiqueta a cada uno.